# Why do we use dynamic memory in ccNUMA systems when we talk about data distribution into locality domains by first touch policy?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmp, numa

In many books when they talk about firch touch policy in ccNUMA systems they are using dynamic memory allocation(dynamic arrays as example) when they distribute data across locality domains.What if for example have an array in stack?Does first touch policy work in the same way?

Comment: *What if for example have an array in stack?* I don't see why it would be different.  On first touch the kernel is creating the viritual-to-physical mapping no matter what the source of the memory is - stack, heap, `mmap()`'d anonymous memory, SYSV shared memory.  I don't see why the actions should be any different for any of those.  The easiest way to know is test and actually dump the physical mappings.

Comment: What the books typically ignore is the idea of "pre-owned memory."  That is, when memory that is returned by malloc (or on the stack) has been touched before, the OS will not re-assign the pages according to the pattern of touch the memory.  Thus, you will see that the first-touch idea does not work any more and that the memory layout in the NUMA domains will be rather constant (assuming no automatic page migration). For the stack, there's a slightly better chance that the stack pages have been touched before.